# How can I install the crond service on an ubuntu server 16.4?

Tags: server, bash, cron, amazon-ec2

I am trying to add a cron job to backup a database on my server (instance EC2 t2 micro, ubuntu 16.4 server). The script works, and the cron line should be ok:

```
* * * * * /home/ubuntu/backup.sh
```

Yet, it was not executed. So I did:

```
service crond status
```

and got:

```
● crond.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

when I do :

```
service crond start
```

I get:

```
Failed to start crond.service: Access denied
See system logs and 'systemctl status crond.service' for details.
```

Being very unskilled with bash things, and considering it might be related to the way Amazon EC2 ubuntu is set up, here I am. Do you know what I could do to get the crond service back up?

EDIT: well, so the service name was `cron`. And it is executed every minute as it should. I guess there is an issue with my script.

Comment: It should be cron not crond. What is the output of  `service cron status`

Comment: My bad. It is executed every minute as it should.

Comment: @stumblebee you should post a quick answer so that it ends up with some kind of closure :-). Thanks by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check the status of cron run:

`service cron status`

Instead of "crond"